# Unable to log into WordPress site after core updates

Tags: wordpress, debugging

I have restored a WordPress website by manually copying the files on top of an empty WordPress installation on a new domain/host. I also imported the database.

The site wasn't working so I updated the WP core, the themes and plugins. The core/themes update was fine but there were a couple of warnings and an error when updating plugins.

Currently the site is very slow and allows me to browse if I login as a normal user. If I login as admin I get the following error:

```
There has been a critical error on this website.

Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.
```

I enabled debugging:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

There was no debug log in wp-content so I'm assuming no errors were recorded.
I can't install any plugins at the moment bacause admin access isn't working.

How can I debug this issue? Where do I start? Can I enable more levels of debug?

Thanks.